# vb.net TCP Server / Listener commands

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I am writing a program in vb.net (VisualStudio 2017) that will remotely start a stopwatch on another computer using TCP/IP. I have created a server program that sends the "CMD1" command.

```
Function Connected()
    REM Has connected to server and now listening for data from the server
    If RX.BaseStream.CanRead = True Then
        Try
            While RX.BaseStream.CanRead = True
                Dim RawData As String = RX.ReadLine.TrimEnd
                If RawData.ToUpper = "/MSG" Then
                    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf MSG1, "Hello World.")
                Else
                    If RawData = "CMD1" Then
                        Timer2.Start()
                    End If

                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Client.Close()
            CMDBox.Text = "Disconnected"
        End Try
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

The client reads the message (for a test I had it send a msgbox - it was successful) unfortunately it does not want to start the timer. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Probably the start point would be some debugging, if you put a beakpoint in there, does it hit it?  on a quick eye balling notice that one condition (I'm guessing that's the one working?), you're checking upper case with a preceding "/"

Comment: Is it a WinForms `Timer`? Are you calling `Start` on the UI thread? If your answers are "yes" and "no", that's your issue. As the documentation states, that `Timer` is intended for a single-threaded environment. You need to either do everything with it on the UI thread or else use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead.